# need to save contents of table view as txt file and the reload it later

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, reload, save

i need to be able to save the contents of my table view which is given data by an NSMutableArray to a txt file and then need to reopen that file automatically when the window containing the table view. i am making an application for mac
thanks 
this is the code for the data source:

```
#import "tableViewData.h"
#import "Customer.h"
@implementation tableViewData
-(id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    list = nil;
    filepath = @"/Users/Gautambir/Desktop/CustomerNames.txt";
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) {
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    }
    else
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:name,memberNumber ,nil];
        [list writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
}
return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
return [list count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn     *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
Customer *Customer = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
return [Customer valueForKey:identifier];
}

-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
Customer *Customer = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
[Customer setValue:object forKey:identifier];
}


-(void)save{
[list writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
}
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender{
[list addObject:[[Customer alloc]init]];
[tableView reloadData];

NSLog (@"array:%@",list);


}

-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender{
NSInteger row = [tableView selectedRow];
if (row != -1) {
    [list removeObjectAtIndex:row];
}

[tableView reloadData];

}




-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

and this is the .m file for the customer object class:

```
#import "Customer.h"

@implementation Customer

@synthesize name;
@synthesize memberNumber;


-(id) init
{
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    name = @"Test";
    int i = arc4random()%1000000000000000000;
    if (i<0) {
        memberNumber = i*-1;
    }
    else
        memberNumber = i;
}
return self;

}

-(void)dealloc
{
[name release];
[super dealloc];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    name = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"]retain];
    memberNumber = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"memberNumeber"];
}
return self;

}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
[aCoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[aCoder encodeInt:memberNumber forKey:@"memberNumber"];
}

@end
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

im sorry to post another answer - i misread the tags, and my first answer was relying to iOS.
this is the way to do it in OSX:

**saving**

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...  //your array

[array addObject:...]; 
[array addObject:...];
[array addObject:...];
...

// then use an NSData to store the array
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
NSString *path = @"/Users/User/path...";
[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

**retrieving**

```
NSMutableArray *archive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

sebastian

Comment: Dear Sebastian. Your are amazing and a life saver. you can imagine how long I have spent trying to make this work and so many people on SO are rude and don't answer the question but you amazing thanks you sooooooo much. i also have another question that i would like to ask you as u answer questions properly if i want to get say the customer name just from a customer ID on a different window which i can open how would i go about doing that please let me know. thanks u sooooo much again

Comment: hi, first of all: glad i could help,
but then: on stackOverflow its a `rule` tu upvote and accept answers you like ;-) this will close the question and make it disappear from the stream. please do so. for any additional questions, open a new one, its not good practice to mix different questions, for future users who might search something specific here.